# mysql escaping string node js`

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-injection

So I am using node js I have the following mysql query im using the npm mysql library to process the queries.

```
let userName = req.body.userName;   
let sqlStatement = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS exist FROM user where username=${userName}`;
```

is the new es6 syntax automatically prevent mysql injection. 
because when I do this

```
let userName = req.body.userName;   
userName = connection.escape(userName);
let sqlStatement = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS exist FROM user where username=${userName}`;
```

it puts single quotes around my data in the database like so 'myUserName'. Does any one know why this is? or if the new syntax is preventing it automatically.

Comment: _"is the new es6 syntax automatically prevent mysql injection"_. No. ES6 doesn't know about SQL or how to escape it properly. Use the tools that came with the SQL driver that you're using (like `connection.escape()`).

Comment: why not use  a question mark placeholder to do a better code to prevent SQL-Injection ? <br /> ` connection.query ("SELECT COUNT()*) AS exist FROM user where username= ?",[userName]); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escape the data using [] syntax like so

```
result = await database.query(
        "INSERT INTO user SET ?",
        [req.body],
        function(error, result) {
          if (!error) {
            console.log("worked");
          } else {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      );
```